# Force WSPBuilder to include .NET 4.0

Tags: solution-package, wspbuilder

How do I force WSPBuilder (through Visual Studio 2010) to deploy a sattelite .NET 4.0 assembly in the GAC?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this? Thanks,
Claudiu :)

Comment: No, I ended up having to reference a 3.5 assembly after all

Answer (score 1):

- Find your solution file with extension `.wsp`
- Change solution extension to `.CAB`
- Now open this file and you will see different files in it but the one you need to deal with is `manifest.xml`

This is how a `manifest.xml` file created by WSP Builder looks like,

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!-- Solution created by WSPBuilder. 28/06/2013 09:21:25  -->
    <Solution SolutionId="solutionID" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
      <Assemblies>
        <Assembly Location="abc.edgf.asdas.dll" DeploymentTarget="GlobalAssemblyCache">
          <SafeControls>
            <SafeControl Assembly="abc.edgf.asdas, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ewrushdkfjhsdf" Namespace="whatever your namespace is" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />
          </SafeControls>
        </Assembly>
      </Assemblies>
      <TemplateFiles>
```

Comment: This is not a good solution, as I need it to be done automatically in Visual Studio.

Comment: You need to put that in your question then !! anyway just add dll's reference to your project and then change "Copy Local" property of dll to "True" and it will be deployed with solution.

Comment: That's the thing - it will not be deployed since WSP builder will detect that it is an un-managed dll (since it is a 4.0 dll) and therefore will not include it in the wsp